# mySQL Insert only when field is different

Tags: mysql

I am using the following sql statement:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO counter (uid, placeid, lastdate) VALUES
('" . $uid . "', '" . $place->place->id . "', '" . $added . "') 
ON duplicate KEY UPDATE count = count + 1`";
```

This keep tracks of how many times people check in.
I do not want multiple check ins a day, so when if
someone checks in twice a day we do not record it.

If $added = lastdate, I do not want to update the count.

Can this be done with a sql statement?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
"INSERT INTO counter (uid, placeid, lastdate) VALUES
('" . $uid . "', '" . $place->place->id . "', '" . $added . "') 
ON duplicate KEY UPDATE count = count + ('" . $added . "' <> lastdate)"
```

Comment: no, that does not work.  Maybe my variable name made it a little confusing.  $added = the date of the check in.  The count is getting incremented by one.  So if $added = the value of lastdate  then count is not incremented by one